# Check if the update value differs from database stored one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm developing an event calendar, where each hour is a slot that allows users to sign one appointment.

Since there is a feature that allows users to update the slot (and also change date/time) I'd like to perform some check before to update the value, making sure that the slot is free.
So I ended up with a method like this:

```
if Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["start_at = ? AND event_calendar_id = ?", self.start_at, self.id])
  errors.add :base, "You cannot save this appointment in that slot."
  return false
end
```

By the way it creates issues when updating other fields without changing the datetime field, because it finds itself and raises the exception making impossible to update it.

Is there a way I can access database data such as the current id so I can filter out itself from the values, or check if the submitted datetime field is equal to the database one (so i can skip this check).

What's the best way to do this?
Thanks.

P.S. I'm using rails 3.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To exclude `self` from the results just add a condition to your `where` excluding its id. Also save some memory and processor time by calling `exists?`, which just returns true or false instead of fetching an entire row and building a new object:

```
Event.where( :start_at => start_at,
             :event_calendar_id => event_calendar.id ).
      where( "id <> ?", id ).
      exists?
```